# Copy deviceToken from Objective C to JavaScript

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, urbanairship.com

I am trying to copy the deviceToken used by Urban Airship to localStorage in the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    UALOG(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);

    [[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];

    NSString *jsStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"localStorage.setItem('deviceToken', '%@');", deviceToken];
    UALOG(@"%@", jsStatement);

    [super writeJavascript:jsStatement];
}
```

The writeJavascript method is defined in `<PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>` which I import in my `AppDelegate.m` That causes this error,

```
InstallerAppApple[10848:707] -[AppDelegate writeJavascript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e600
```

What I think I need to do is save the deviceId to objective-c's memory, then write a plugin which returns that saved value.

How do I save that deviceId to a global space that I will have access to in my plugin method? How do I get and set global values in objective c? Is there a better way to access the deviceId with PhoneGap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error:

> '-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d190'

Your application's delegate does not implement the 
`-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` selector!

I don't use phone gap, so I don't know what that looks like for a phonegap application.

Comment: My AppDelegate has `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` implemented. The app runs fine when I remove the `writeJavascript` and the `PGPlugin.h ` import

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong error message. Updated it in the question.